# How do I assign duplicate shortcuts?

Tags: visual-studio

VS 2019

Typically, I use "ctrl-c and sometimes ctrl-ins" to copy (both worked).

This sequence --- Tools => Options => Keyboard => Edit.Copy --- does not allow me to assign both.

Likewise and "ctrl-v and shift-ins" to paste.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign multiple shortcut keys to one command from Tools => Options => Environment => Keyboard in Visual Studio. Like for Edit.Copy command there are two shortcuts Ctrl+C and Ctrl+Ins.
[image]

But you can't have same shortcut key for two commands. So if you assign Ctrl+V for Edit.Copy command. Ctrl+V shortcut will be removed from Edit.Paste command.

Comment: True.  However, Ctrl+Ins does not work.  (Shift+Ins does work).  Very strange as previous versions of VS worked fine.  Is there a way to see if Ctrl+Ins has been also assigned to a different command?